# How I can extend a jquery plugin from another for overwrite methods?

Tags: jquery, plugins, extends

I need extend a plugin from another, who is the best way for it???

The extension will be overwrite methods and add any settings too.

I has a **foo** plugin that work well, now... I need extend another plugin **bar** from **foo**.

I write the following code, but is not work:

```
(function($) {
  var methods = {
    'onErrors': function (o, otherErrors) {
    }
  }
  $.extend(true, $[foo][bar].prototype, extensionMethods);
})(jQuery);
```

Now, how should be write a plugin extension??

Thanks

Comment: you need to explain your problem better

Answer (score 1):

From the example code you included, my guess is you're trying to achieve what is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050985/best-way-to-extend-a-jquery-plugin/4414356#4414356).

If that's the case, then there are two issues in play here.

Firstly, you declared your list of methods as `methods` but then try to use it as `extensionMethods`.

Secondly, and more importantly, you seem to have misunderstood the example (or perhaps I misunderstood your requirements?). `$.extend()` will not allow you to create a new plugin **bar** from **foo**. You can however extend **foo** with additional methods. Like so:

```
(function($) {
   var extensionMethods = {
      // ....
   }
   $.extend($.fn.foo, extensionMethods);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly look in to the [jQuery Hook](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryHook) extension?

Though I'm not 100% sure what you're wanting to do. Some example code would be great (or better explain what you're trying to accomplish).

**EDIT**

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440068/is-there-any-unobtrusive-way-to-hook-into-jquery-methods-for-triggers/440517#440517) on the essence of function hooking.

Comment: Dear Brad, no... I not need a hook, I need extend a plugin from another plugin.

Comment: I has a foo plugin that work well, now... I need extend another plugin bar from foo.
I write the following code, but is not work:
[code]
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        'onErrors': function (o, otherErrors) {
        }
    }
    $.extend(true, $[foo][bar].prototype, extensionMethods);
})(jQuery);
[code]
Now, how should be write a plugin extension??

Comment: @Yecid: All depends on access levels/exposure of the methods. If you wrote the plugins, I would advise making them more modular so extending them is feasible (much like jQuery does with the `$.extend` ability)